# Remove file from Apache using servlet

Tags: java, apache, servlets

I'm uploading files using servlet my little code is like this:

```
ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

try {
    fileItemsList = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);
} catch (FileUploadException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(iThink.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

String optionalFileName = "";
FileItem fileItem = null;

Iterator it = fileItemsList.iterator();
...
```

The file is uploaded to apache directory (\webapps\mysite\uploads\abd.zip). Uploading is working fine but I want to delete it.

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself? I good place to start is [java file delete](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=java+file+delete)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already got a list of `FileItem` objects you can simply iterate over that list and call [FileItem#delete](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#delete%28%29) on the items. Alternatively use [File#delete](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) from Java's standard library.

Comment: i made little mistake in directory so its working fine now thank you for your reply..